# Use series data but display custom text on top of columns Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to use highchart, working with colums.

My series data are some hours.
For example, if my data is 23.75, it means 23:45 hours.

I would like to use my 23.75 data so that my colums are in the right place, but the little text on top of my column displays "23:45".

Is it possible ? I can't find the right option to do this.

Thanks in advance !

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it !

```
stackLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
           return this.total // custom text label here
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can format data label values by [`formatter`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.dataLabels.formatter)

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function () {
        return this.y;     // you can update datalabel values here
    }
}
```

Comment: This displays my label inside the colum. I guess it's fine but I'd really like to put it on top of the colum ! :) Thanks for the tip, I'll use this for now...

Comment: @Thibaut Tang, you can use the `dataLabels` with disabled `inside` option: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/asd7y50e/